# Equivalent of "highly dynamic" appearance in markdown presentations

Tags: rstudio, markdown, r-markdown, presentation

I am considering making my presentations using markdown in RStudio rather than beamer. In beamer I often use incremental appearance of the content, with the option "highly dynamic", which makes the next item to appear show in light gray before appearing fully. Apart from looking nice, this helps me present as it prevents me from being surprised if I forget the next point on the slide.

My question is: Is there any way to achieve a similar effect if I make my slides in RStudio, for instance as an R presentation, or rmarkdown presentation using ioslides, or Slidy?

I am aware that I can set `incremental: true` in R presentations, but this only gives incremental appearance, not the "highly dynamic" effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to produce slides in RMarkdown:  `ioslides`, `slidy`, `revealjs`, `xaringan`, etc.  I tend to use `ioslides`, and this method works there.  I have added a couple of other
variations below.

What you need to do is to change the CSS for the selector `.build .to-build` so that instead of making items transparent, it only makes them partially transparent.  You can do this by creating a file containing this:

```
.build .to-build {
  opacity: 0.1
}
```

If you call that file `incremental.css`, then in your YAML for the presentation, you have this:

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: true
    css: incremental.css
```

Then you will see something like this when you display the sample presentation after showing the first bullet:

[image: screenshot]

Edited to add:

Here's the CSS to use if you're using `slidy_presentation` instead of `ioslides_presentation`:

```
body.single_slide .invisible {
  opacity: 0.1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And here's what to use for `revealjs::revealjs_presentation`:

```
.reveal .slides section .fragment {
  opacity: 0.1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

You can probably put all three recipes into the `incremental.css` file, and then switch between the formats until you find which one you like best.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making beamer presentations from Rmarkdown, this works:

```
---
output:
    beamer_presentation:
        incremental: true
header-includes:
    - \setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
---

- one
- two
- three
```

[image: rmd-generated beamer slides with incremental bullets]